# Reason: Invalid template property or properties [Api]

Tags: aws-sam

After deploy_image through docker, I have found:

> Waiting for changeset to be created..
>
> Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED.

What is wrong with my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'testimg

  Sample SAM Template for testimg

  '
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
Api:
  BinaryMediaTypes:
  - image/png
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: 
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - HelloWorldFunction
      - Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - HelloWorldFunctionRole
      - Arn
```

I expect it will create a stack in cloudformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your template there:

1. The top level of your template has a key `Api` that is unrecognised by SAM/CloudFormation. See docs [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#globals-section). It looks like you have the indentation wrong, whereas your globals section should be:

```yaml
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
  Api:
    BinaryMediaTypes:
    - image/png
```

2. Your `CodeUri` field is empty. That should be the local path to your Python code, like `CodeUri: hello_world/`.

If you fix those issues, it should deploy.

Comment: Hi alex if I am not mistake, the Api would be
`
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
  Api:
    BinaryMediaTypes:
    - image~1png
`

and I already have the code uri...but still the same issue

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman, there is an example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/implicit_api_settings/template.yaml#L14-L17). As I said, your indentation is wrong, and that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: yes, I have changed that, but having same issue again.

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman, [here](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/819cc46a45392a2686713075c856bc54) is a Gist showing how I reproduced your error, then I fixed the indentation problem, and then it shows it deploys.

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman, you're welcome. Would you be so kind as to accept the answer by selecting the green tick?